# Formating Date.toString() output in JAVA

Tags: java, date, jcalendar

I'm using JComboCalendar widget to let the user select a date. JComboCalendar has a method getDate() which returns a Date object.

[According to Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString%28%29), Date.toString should return a string with the format yyyy-mm-dd, but instead I'm receiving strings like:

```
Fri Nov 08 13:08:38 CET 2013
```

How can I get the expected output? Bonus for how to format it like dd-mm-yyyy, since I just found how to read a String in a given format, not how to format the output.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is not the same as `java.util.Date`. You're basically looking at the completely wrong javadoc.

Comment: @BalusC agreed. you need to check your import Roman!!

Comment: Nice catch @BalusC ! My imports are ok, I just made a mistake when looking for documentation at Google :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to format your date:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(comboCalendar.getDate())
```

As to your other question, you opened the wrong documentation.
`getDate()` returns a `java.util.Date` not a `java.sql.Date`
Correct documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will help you.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 String str = sdf.format(yourDateInstance);
```

Comment: I didn't downvoted this, but this is more suitable as a comment, not as an informative answer. UPDATE: Also a mystery why people upvote this! The author didn't even put a link to SimpleDateFormat...

Comment: yes, i'm thinking what is the context for the downvote. :(
I see, you are seeking for the code.

Comment: This better suits in comment not in answer

Comment: Fine, I will pay attention next time.

Comment: @duffymo to be fair, this doesn't answer the main question so it should have been a comment. And even then, just tossing a class name out there doesn't even really answer the other question.

Comment: @TerryZhao There are 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes because some think(including me) that this is not an answer.Update your answer giving some codes,so that future users will not downvote.Well I am **not** the downvoter

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d=new Date();
    System.out.println(d1.format(d));
```

**output** 2013-11-08

Answer (score -1):

Try this out :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatDate.format(new Date()); // Sample date to be formatted
System.out.println(formattedDate); // Watch the output
```

Comment: this will print 2013-41-08

Comment: Because `mm` is minutes, not months. Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead.